# ¿Cómo crear un programa en java para dividir un archivo cualquiera?

Tags: java

Hace unos días en el trabajo me encomendaron crear un programa que automatizara una de las tantas tareas que lo hacen de forma manual. La tarea consiste en comprimir dos archivos, el primero es un .bak (backup de SQL Server) y el otro archivo generado por el visual FoxPro (file), no me dieron más detalles, el punto es que estos se comprimen (winrar) en paquetes de 100MB tantas vences el tamaño así lo amerite, estos se guardan en una carpeta cada uno (ya comprimidos y divididos) y se pone en otra carpeta de donde mediante un FTP se envía a un host externo.

Esta proceso lo repiten todos los días, y pues se han visto en la necesidad de automatizarlo, he estado buscando en la red sin mucho éxito, cualquier idea de cómo comenzar sería de mucha ayuda, incluso si no es con java.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para el correcto funcionamiento debes usar la librería [`commons-io`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.5), tomado como referencia el código publicado, he realizado algunas mejoras y parametrizaciones:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Zipping {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // tamaño de cada parte de los archivos en MB
        int fileSize = 100;
        // archivo a comprimir
        String fileToSplit = "/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/Desktop/backupDb.bak";
        splitAndZipFile(new File(fileToSplit), fileSize);
    }

    public static void splitAndZipFile(File inputFile, int size) throws IOException {

        int counter = 1;
        int byteSize = 1024;
        byte[] b;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[byteSize * byteSize * size];
        File newFile;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        ZipOutputStream out;
        String temporalName;
        String compressedFilename;
        String outputFileName;

        try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile))) {

            String fileName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(inputFile.getName());
            String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(inputFile.getName());
            int tmp;

            while ((tmp = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                temporalName = String.format("%s.%03d", fileName, counter);
                newFile = new File(inputFile.getParent(), temporalName);

                try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile)) {
                    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, tmp);
                }

                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(newFile);
                // directorio donde se va a exportar los archivos
                outputFileName = String.format("/Volumes/Stonehall/juanca/Desktop/%s00%s.zip", fileName, counter);
                out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFileName));

                compressedFilename = String.format("parte_00%s.%s", counter, fileExtension);
                out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(compressedFilename));

                b = new byte[byteSize];
                int count;

                while ((count = fileInputStream.read(b)) > 0) {
                    out.write(b, 0, count);
                }

                counter++;
                fileInputStream.close();
                out.close();

                FileUtils.deleteQuietly(newFile);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Proceso finalizado!");
    }
}
```

*Por si a alguien le sirve aquí está el [repositorio](https://github.com/juanca87/cmd-zipper) con el código*

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, las dos primeras librerías que hacen referencia al apache no existen, me salen en rojo.

Comment: Si, si estas usando `maven` puedes agregar la dependencia `commons-io` al pom (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.5), sino puedes descargarte el `jar` y agregarle al classpath de tu proyecto.

Comment: Gracias, ¿Hay alguna forma de solucionar el inconveniente de la descompresión? ¿Para que cuando lo descomprima me devuelva un solo archivo? Por que literalmente lo divide, pero luego no puedo integrarlo.

Comment: He usando `rar` (http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) para comprimir y descomprimir archivos desde la consola. Quizás te sirva chequear si soporta comprimir y descomprimir en paquetes, si es así, podrías automatizar el proceso creando un script (batch/shell - dependiendo de tu plataforma).

Comment: Así es, al final tuve y vi que la opción más viable es mediante el uso "directo" del programa (WinRAR, 7za, WinZip, etc) mediante la consola. Y es así como pude luego programarlo para que se ejecute en el programador de tareas de Windows...

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un metodo para hacer lo que necesitas.

```
public static  void splitAndZipFile(File f) throws IOException {

        int partCounter=0;
        int counter=1;
        int sizeOfFiles = (1024 * 1024)*100;// 100MB
        byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfFiles];

        try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f))) {//try-with-resources para asegurar que se cierran los buffers.

            String name = f.getName();

                int tmp = 0;
                while ((tmp = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    //Nombramos cada parte con un identificador al final, para que no se sobreescriba.
                    File newFile = new File(f.getParent(), name+ "." + String.format("%03d", partCounter++));

                    //Grabamos el fichero temporal(que sera borrado posteriormente)
                    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile)) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, tmp);//tmp is chunk size
                    }

                    //Leemos el nuevo fichero
                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(newFile);
                    //Creamos el zip con el fichero
                    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("WebContent\\pru\\temp\\zip"+counter+".zip"));

                    //Creamos la entrada dentro del zip
                    out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("parte"+counter+".txt")); 

                    //Agregamos el contenido del fichero al zip
                    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                    int count;

                    while ((count = in.read(b)) > 0) {
                        out.write(b, 0, count);
                    }
                    counter++;
                    in.close();
                    out.close();

                    if(newFile.exists()){
                       newFile.delete();
                    }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Termine!");
    }



public static void main (String[] args){

         try {
            splitAndZipFile(new File("WebContent\\pru\\texp2\\archivo.txt"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
```

Espero que te sirva!

Cualquier cosa me dices.

**NOTA:** ahora esta cogiendo fuerza el uso de `node.js` y `gulp` o `grunt` o similares para automatizar tareas. Nunca he trabajado con dichas tecnologias en este ambito por lo que no me atrevo a decirte nada, pero es otra buena alternativa por si quieres echarle un ojo.

**EDIT:** en la linea `ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("WebContent\\pru\\temp\\zip"+counter+".zip"));` defines donde vas a mandar el zip comprimido, para mandarlo al escritorio bastaria con diejarlo `ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\tu_usuario\\Desktop\\zip"+counter+".zip"));` pero bueno todo seria ver tu ruta

Comment: Gracias por responder, tengo un inconveniente con la siguiente línea de código: `FileUtils.deleteQuietly(newFile);` .

Comment: Sale el mensaje: "cannot symbol". Otra cosa que quería consultar es sobre la dirección del archivo que se va ha comprimir, como lo especifico en caso que esté en el escritorio por ejemplo.

Comment: Buenas he editado mi respuesta, perdona que se me paso, como bien dicen abajo esa clase pertenece a la librería de common-io, si ves mi edición ahora lo borro de la manera básica. He agregado ademas info sobre tu duda de la ruta.Prueba y me dices.

Comment: Gracias, ¿Hay alguna forma de solucionar el inconveniente de la descompresión? es decir, cuando yo uso un programa como el winrar y divido  un archivo.exe (lo acabo de hacer), lo que hago es descomprimir la parte1.zip y se descomprime TODO el archivo, en este caso la partición se hace de forma aislada y no hay forma de recuperarlo integramente, no sé si me dejé entender.

Comment: Comprendo lo que necesitas pero no se si es posible, lo que he encontrado es una librería [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/), esto te permitiría comprimir un archivo y partirlo en varios trozos según una longitud que tu decidas, si esto te vale dímelo y edito mi respuesta, pero creo que no te valdría ya que tu necesitarías primero partir el fichero y posteriormente comprimir cada parte y ligarla de alguna manera a la anterior que eso no se si es posible